# How to detect if Facebook page is unpublished using Linux script

Tags: facebook

I've created many business/company pages in Facebook. But regularly Facebook unpublishes them.

I'd like to check whether a page is unpublished using some script on Linux which can notify me.

How can I do it?

There is related thread: [Facebook API: Determine if Facebook Page is published / unpublished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840569/facebook-api-determine-if-facebook-page-is-published-unpublished) and curl command mentioned does not seem to be working correctly when I tried on my Linux command prompt.

Comment: _“But regularly Facebook unpublishes them”_ – my guess would be, that there’s a _reason_ for that …? Maybe better if you tried not to violate their policies/TOS in the first place.

Comment: After publishing again without changes it works fine for many days. Sometimes it is unpublished for inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need a User Access Token with `manage_pages` permission. Then, you should be able to do the following:

```
 curl -4 "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20page_id%2C%20name%2C%20username%2C%20is_published%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me())%20AND%20is_published%3D0%20ORDER%20BY%20fan_count%20DESC&access_token={user_access_token}"
```

and replace `{user_access_token}` with your actual User Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

Call https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID and check, if a "Unsupported get request" is returned. If yes, then it *can* be, that the page is unpublished.

This attempt is not going to work for age-restricted pages! They always return "Unsupported get request" when calling the Graph API endpoint with no access token.